# For I/Q data do I need to know center frequency?

Tags: signal-processing, fft, frequency, frequency-analysis, software-defined-radio

Say I have I/Q data collected from a SDR with know sampling rate `Fs` but unknown center frequency `Fc`. If I plot frequency spectrum it will range from `(-Fs/2)` to `(+Fs/2)`. So can I infer anything out of that (Eg. which frequencies are present) or I need to know the center frequency explicitly ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for baseband IQ data from an SDR, you need to know the center frequency (and possibly an offset) to know the originating RF frequency.

In the process of an SDR creating IQ samples, the original RF (radio frequency) is mixed, (super)heterodyned, or converted (and filtered) so that the RF spectrum that was at some higher RF frequency is now centered at 0 Hz in frequency (unless there was an offset).  So you have to add that center frequency back to know with what RF frequency any signal from the antenna originated before it got to the SDR receiver.